# Android 13 onGoing notifications

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-dependencies, android-notifications

I have noticed a different behaviour regarding to persistent notification. It started when building notifications with [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications). I want to build a notification, that continuously shows status of something. It's not a timer, but something I could update at least every second.

When I use android 10, notifications can't be dismissed by swipe, as expected, but when I use Android 13 on Pixel 7, no matter what notification, I can remove it from the history.

I tested it in Kotlin and I get the same result, no matter what, on Android 13, I can dismiss every notification I generate.

I've found some real world examples, where the app sends another notification when it's been dismissed, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sounds like Android is protecting its users against malicious apps that want to perma-show notifications. Good.

Comment: does that mean it's impossible to display those "sticky" notifications like before? I didn't find any information on that